# MySql database backup dump file to oracle 11g

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, database-migration

I have a Mysql database backup dump file (`.sql`), and I want to migrate this file directly into Oracle by using `sqldeveloper`. Will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work. If you do it manually from a dump, you would have to do a lot of data conversion, modify the create table code to work for oracle and so on. It would be a lot of work.

But if you have SQL Developer, it apparently has a process to do precisely that.

Check out that link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be realized in automatic mode, due to different basic syntax of Oracle and MySQL dump files. In addition, Orqcle uses its own RMAN utility for controlling backups and restoration.

A most viable solution is to write a script converting MySQL dump file into the format recognizable by Oracle. I guess these procedures can exist in Internet, available for (free?) downloading.